# Difference between field_data and field_revision tables?

Tags: 7, database

I have a lot of custom functions; I just want to make sure I'm doing this right.
If I want the most recent version—the live version—of a node, I go to the `field_data_field_xyz` table, right?

My understanding is the `field_revision_field_xyz` keeps all older versions, correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is correct: [Working with Field SQL Storage](http://drupal.org/node/890070).

> **Database tables:**
>
> - {field_data_[field_name]} Standard data storage for a field.
> - {field_revision_[field_name]} Standard revision storage for a field.

Comment: It's not very recommended to query these tables directly but I'll do it on many projects. Have a look at [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) and this [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-do-you-build-a-query-to-get-a-series-of-nodes-and-their-field-values-filtered/3506#3506).

Comment: Yeah there were a bunch of places where Views just wouldn't cut it.  What's the biggest downfall to querying the tables directly though?

Comment: IN D6 it was that field could change from the tabtle `content_type_*` to its own table, so you'd better use the API to build your query. In D7 this doesn't happen anymore so that's better ;)

Comment: This answer is not 100% clear.  If I needed to write SQL to be able to export the most current data, can I simply ignore the `field_revision_field_*` tables, or do I need to incorporate them into my export somehow, and if so, how?